# How can I add ads in my React Native app?

Tags: reactjs, admob, ads

I have been trying to add ads to my react native app.
I tried using react-native-admob and  expo-ads-admob following each steps they say for set up and  configuration but everytime I install any of those libraries in my app, it just stops working.

I even create a new project and installed the libraries on it, hoping it to work for not having anything else installed but the app also stoped working.

the worst is I can't see any error message in the console, but the app just doesn't work in the emulator. If I try to open it, it just won't open and a message says "App keeps stoping"

I am using react native version 0.62.2

is there a way in 2020 to add ads in a react native app?

Answer (score 0):

yeah you can ! did you tested it on a real phone ? you must see your Logcat to detect the problem .
you must detect problem to fix it .

you can add an issue at react-native-admob page in github :
https://github.com/sbugert/react-native-admob/issues